# Using Slick.js in React with "infinite: true", slides are rendered multiple times

Tags: reactjs, slick.js

1. If I have 1 slide and refresh the page, one API call = total no. of slides. This is expected.
2. When I have 2 or more slides then it will automatically create 2 + 3 = 5 slides. So, API calls > total no. of slides. If I set `infinite:false` then it will load the actual slides. So, API calls = total no. of slides.

Shouldn't there be one API call per slide, even when using `infinite: true`?

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import Slider from "react-slick";

 export default class SimpleSlider extends Component {
   render() {
     const settings = {
       dots: true,
       infinite: true,
       speed: 500,
       slidesToShow: 1,
       slidesToScroll: 1
     };
     return (
       <div>
         <h2> Slick Multiple Render Issue</h2>
         <Slider {...settings}>
           <ChildComponent />
         </Slider>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

ChildComponent have some logic which make api call....

Comment: For the "infinite" effect, Slick clones slides and adds them before and after your existing slides. Are you creating your slide contents before calling Slick or are you using react-slick with child components?

Comment: Can you post your code to the question?

Comment: Hi, @EdLucas code added in question. please have a look.